# How can i add some space between two buttons (Flutter fire ui)

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-authentication, flutter-layout, firebaseui

[image: fluter ui image]

How can i add space between sign in button and sign in with google, please not that its is flutter fire ui, i just use bellow built in functions which automatically implement the ui.

providerConfigs: const [
EmailProviderConfiguration(),
GoogleProviderConfiguration(
clientId: '316263778394:android:7ce6031f0d41db0503b063',
),
PhoneProviderConfiguration(),
],

Comment: Can you include [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score -1):

From your code it looks like `providerConfigs` takes `List<Widget>` as argument and arranges the `Widget`s vertically.

If that's true then you can just add `SizedBox(height: <desired height>, width: 1)` in-between the two elements you want to add space.

I believe the below code should work:

```
providerConfigs: const [
    EmailProviderConfiguration(),
    GoogleProviderConfiguration( clientId: '316263778394:android:7ce6031f0d41db0503b063', ),
    SizedBox(height: 20, width: 1),
    PhoneProviderConfiguration(),
],
```

You can add a `const` declaration for the SizedBox.

Comment: Hi Abhijit Gosh, I have tried by adding sized box in between them, but it shows error like "The element type 'SizedBox' can't be assigned to the list type 'ProviderConfiguration'. "

Comment: Is `ProviderConfiguration` a custom widget made by you? In that case you need to add `SizedBox` type in the definition of `ProviderConfiguration`

Comment: No its defined by flutter fire ui package

Comment: In that case I don't think you have access over the UI